# What is the prohibition in women attending immodest parties?

Tags: women, tznius-modesty, kedusha-holiness, parties-celebrations

Although females are not subject to the same prohibition as men, I am assuming that attending a party in which there are others immodestly dressed should also be a questionable environment for women. Is there any specific prohibition, besides constantly ensuring a *kadosh* environment?

Comment: I would assume it would be prohibited?

Comment: Do you mean a party with women only, or a mixed party?

Comment: Let's say women only..

Comment: @Yaakov Remember to [edit] any clarifications into the post itself.

Comment: As far as I know, the concept of *tzniut* applies regardless of whether an event is single gender or not. There is a separate problem of men and women swimming together or being at certain other public events that have other concerns beyond tzniut (modesty).

Comment: Please describe your situation more understandably.

Comment: If it is a environment of peritzut which could arouse hirhurei aveira this may be a Torah Lav